# How to define the return type as array with its properties in PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP interface and its concrete class as below.

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    public function methodA(array $data): array;
}

class ClassA implements InterfaceA
{
    public function methodA(array $data): array
    {
        // method stuffs

        return [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Name 1'
        ];
    }
}
```

I need a way to strictly define the return type (array) with its properties (id, name) in the interface method.

The intention of this is when someone implements the same interface for another concrete class (say ClassB), he might have missed some properties (like 'name') from the returned array.

Is there a way in PHP (I'm using PHP 8.0), to avoid this mistake?

Comment: make it a value object and so define the return type as this object

Comment: Can you please give me a code example for the above methodA() function? @YourCommonSense

Comment: 1. create a class with your required fields. 2. make this function return this class' instance instead of array. Make this interface return type this class. what's unclear here?

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a specific class for the return type, and return not an array but an instance of this class ?! Because if think (I may be wrong) array in php are flexible and you cannot force array return type to contain a certain key.

Your class will then be :

```php
class ReturnClassTest {
    public function __construct(public int $id, public string $name) {}
}

interface InterfaceA
{
    public function methodA(array $data): ReturnClassTest;
}

class ClassA implements InterfaceA
{
    public function methodA(array $data): ReturnClassTest
    {
        // method stuffs
        return new ReturnClassTest(1, 'Name 1');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was actually looking for a way to return an "array" type but it seems there is no way in PHP to do it without creating another class for the return type :)